# What is wrong with the syntax in this?

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#Catid').change(function(){
                var optvalue = $(this).val(),
                div = $('#' + 'parentid' + optvalue);
                $('div').hide();
                div.show();
            });
        });​ 
              </script>
```

Im getting a console error but I have no idea why

Comment: What error are you getting? Always helpful to provide that. May also be worth sharing what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you have an issue with the last line. Theres a hidden character right at the end there.
Delete it and write it again, that should sort it!

Comment: Ah geat, found it out in the other thread actually, yeh that was the problem, cheers for your help though!

Comment: Oh, well my pleasure, but perhaps you should stick to one thread per problem, that'd stop this sort of spill over :)

Comment: Is there an online tool for checking stuff like that? What did you use to find it, David?

Comment: Yup yup, notepadd++ :)

Though if he checks his javascript console in firefox or chrome it should also find the exact line with the issue

Comment: Thank you, I asked because two IDEs didn't recognize that, and I remember some time ago when I needed stuff like that, so I wondered if there's an online tool now.

Comment: Hmmm, can't see anything wrong in my notepad++ either... There is a regular space after the last semi-colon, but that's it.

Answer (score 2):

You've asked "What is wrong with the syntax in this", so I figured I should point this one out too.

The problem is with this code here:

```
div = $('#' + 'parentid' + optvalue);
```

The div is a global variables and it is consider bad practice.

A better way to rewrite this is to include this as part of the initial var.

```
var optvalue = $(this).val(),
    div      = $('#' + 'parentid' + optvalue);
```

Comment: Oh, so if I do this instead:
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#Catid').change(function(){
      var optvalue = $(this).val();
      var newbit = $('#' + 'parentid' + optvalue);
      $('newbit').hide();
      $(newbit).show();
     });
    });
Is that better?

Comment: Yes, that will work as well, but it would best to add additional variable with commas instead of using "var" for every new ones. So "var x = 1; var y = 5; var z = 10;" is the same as "var x = 1, y = 5, z = 10;"